# Debug Tomcat deployed code with cargo plugin

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, cargo, maven-cargo

Can anyone please tell how to debug the code in eclipse with [Cargo(Tomcat)](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html) plugin?

We are using Java 8, Tomcat 8, eclipse Juno in Windows 7 OS.

One other thing I want to mention is, we don't have control to modify Tomcat scripts as the tomcat is freshly getting installed from Nexus repository(or from local repo cache) for every execution of `mvn -P dev clean package cargo:run`.

Answer (score 3):

For debug Cargo, you can configure you container like by this:

```
<container>
  <containerId>tomcat4x</containerId>
  <home>c:/apps/jakarta-tomcat-4.1.30</home>
  <log>target/cargo.log</log>
  <logLevel>debug</logLevel>
</container>
```

If you want to debug container, then set JVM with this:

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=<suspend>,address=<port>
-Xnoagent
-Djava.compiler=NONE
```

More information about Cargo debugging is [here](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Debugging.html).

I wrote a blog post about maven cargo plugin for using integration test. Maybe it will help you. http://hrabosch.com/2016/06/12/how-to-run-integration-tests-with-cargo-maven-plugin-in-a-separate-container/
There is Jetty, but you can change it to tomcat.

Comment: A link to a resource is fine. You still need to provide more information in the answer itself.